# Failed to apply the firewall configuration

Tags: ubuntu, plesk

I want to activate Firewall extension but i get error messag as you can see right below.

"Command '['/usr/local/psa/var/modules/firewall/firewall-new.sh']' timed out after 14.999689102172852 seconds"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wIdR.png)

Any ideas how to activate it?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and Plesk version is the latest one.

Comment: Questions involving web panels like Plesk are off topic.